# How to halt execution until Promise is resolved

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I just started working with promises and so far they are great. However, the software I am writing at the moment requires me to collect all promises and get an aggregated result of them. This process has to finish before the code can continue executing, as the future execution depends on the result.

For a validation framework I make validation requests in the form of promises, these get stored (and are async) in an array. When I click the submit button it should await all validation promises and only execute if all promises are resolved successfully. This is done with the following code, which should return false but unfortunately returns true:

```js
console.log(valid());

function valid() {
  // ...
  some_prev = true;
  pending = [
    new Promise(function(resolve) {
      setTimeout(function() {console.log('done resolve'); resolve(true);}.bind(this), 2000);
    }),
    new Promise(function(reject) {
      setTimeout(function() {console.log('done reject'); reject(false);}.bind(this), 4000);
    })
  ];
  
  if (some_prev && collectPending(pending).then(val => {return true;}).catch(err => {return false;})) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

function collectPending(pending) {
  var p = Promise.all(pending)
    .then(values => {
      return true;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      return false;
    });
    
  return p;
}
```

The `valid` method should return true as the form will otherwise be submitted while it contains errors.

I have also tried wrapping the `Promise.all` in a async function but I found that this only pushes the problem further on and in the end you always end up in a similar situation.

**In essence, is there a wait to halt the execution until all promises are resolved?**

**Edit 27-01-2021 15:38:**
As I am extending a framework, I am only allowed to overwrite the `valid` method. The rest of this framework expects the `valid` method to be sync. **So I am really looking for a way to convert async back to sync instead of making all the code async.** The `collectPending` method I wrote myself, so this one can be changes, just not the `valid` method.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work as per your expectation, it is executing in the order one may want to have.

```js
valid().then(res => console.log(res));

async function valid() {
  // ...
  some_prev = true;
  pending = [
    new Promise(function(resolve) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('done resolve');
        resolve(true);
      }.bind(this), 2000);
    }),
    new Promise(function(reject) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('done reject');
        reject(false);
      }.bind(this), 4000);
    })
  ];
  // wait for collectPending to resolve 
  if (some_prev && await collectPending(pending)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

async function collectPending(pending) {
  let result = await Promise.all(pending);
  return result.reduce((res, current) => res && current); //combines result of all the promises and return the boolean 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately this does not work as I am extending a framework and I'm only allowed to overwrite the ```valid``` method. So I am really looking for a way to convert async back to sync.

Comment: Well if you want the result of valid, and it's an async function itself, i.e deals with promises, valid() will never work without using then

Comment: If we can't modify collectPending, We can manage that, Do you want me to modify the answer for that ?

Comment: That is unfortunate.. I would assume that converting async back to sync is a regular operation performed? Any ways, the ```collectPending``` method can be changed to suit the needs as it is a method I wrote myself and is only called in the overwritten ```valid``` method.

Comment: If you want to use promises then I would prefer this way, otherwise, we can always do callbacks